# Prime factorization of $\frac{3^{41} -1}{2}$

Tags: number-theory

How can  I determine all prime factor of  $\frac{3^{41} -1}{2}$ without doing prime factorizations.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In a fairly recent question (yesterday?) I gave a proof that $83$ divides our number. The other factors are not easy to get at by hand.

Comment: [Found it!](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1749042/without-using-prime-factorization-find-a-prime-factor-of-frac341-12/1749044#1749044)

Comment: I suppose you can repeatedly use $(a^2-1)=(a-1)(a+1)$ and that $3^n+1$ is even?

Comment: You know that $3$ is a square modulo any prime divisor $p$, so $p\equiv \pm 1\pmod{12}$. You also know that $41\mid p-1$, or $p\equiv 1\pmod {41}$. So $p\equiv 1,83\pmod{41\cdot 12}$. That reduces your search for prime divisors somewhat, but given the actual factorization, probably not enough.

Comment: I'd say that the method is similar as for the Mersenne numbers $2^p-1$ (with $p$ prime) which if composite have divisors of the form $2kp+1$ (in particular the least prime divisor of $2^p-1$ is of this form)

Comment: The fact that $83$ divides $3^{41}$ can be established by hand:
Modulo $83=3^4+2$, we have $3^n\equiv 4\cdot 3^{n-8}$, hence
$$3^{41}\equiv  4\cdot 3^{33}\equiv \ldots \equiv 4^{5}\cdot 3\equiv 28\cdot 3\equiv 1$$

Answer (score 3):

Due to the particular form of that number, its prime factors are restricted to a very specific subset of the prime numbers. If $p>41$ and 
$$ 3^{41}\equiv 1\pmod{p},$$
it follows that the order of $3$ in $\mathbb{F}_p^*$ is exactly $41$, so $41\mid (p-1)$ by Lagrange's theorem, or:
$$ p\equiv 1\pmod{41}.$$
The first prime in such a subset is $p=83$. In such a case,
$$ 3^{41}\equiv 3^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv \left(\frac{3}{p}\right) \equiv 1\pmod{p}$$
by quadratic reciprocity, since $83\equiv -1\pmod{4}$ gives $\left(\frac{-1}{83}\right)=-1$ and $89\equiv -1\pmod{3}$ gives $\left(\frac{-3}{83}\right)=-1$, so $\left(\frac{3}{83}\right)=1$. You may check that no prime in the interval $[2,41]$ is a divisor of $\frac{3^{41}-1}{2}$, hence $\frac{3^{41}-1}{2}$ is $83$ times the product of some (huge) primes $\equiv 1\pmod{41}$.

It won't be an easy problem in the general case. For instance, to test numbers of the form $2^p-1$ (or $\frac{3^p-1}{2}$ with $p\equiv\pm 5\pmod{12}$) for primality is actually the main way to generate colossal primes (like $\frac{3^7-1}{2}=1093$, that is not so huge but is a neat example). On the other hand, the same argument as above shows that for any prime $p$, there are infinite primes $\equiv 1\pmod{p}$.